# Internet Explorer 11 keeps splitting words

Tags: css, split, internet-explorer-11, words

Internet explorer keeps on splitting my words. Chrome and Firefox are working fine.

Here is my code and the link to the website: http://www.hgsainc.com/about/
Thanks for your help!

```
.page #main .entry-content {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
    word-wrap: normal;
    -webkit-hyphens: none;
    -moz-hyphens: none;
    hyphens: none;
    table-layout: fixed;  
}

.page #main .entry-content p,
.page #main .entry-content span {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: splitting what words, can you be more specfic?

Comment: A question should contain enough code (here, HTML and CSS) for reproducing the problem. A link to a live page is *not* enough, as the question then becomes meaningless to future visitors when the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't looked at your site, but it looks like you need to add the `-ms-hyphens` prefix to your css. You have the `-webkit` and `-moz` but no `-ms`:

```
-ms-hyphens: none;
```

See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771871(v=vs.85).aspx

Also, after looking into it a bit more, it looks like Opera doesn't support this, and neither do most mobile browsers: http://caniuse.com/css-hyphens - Just a heads up in case you come across that down the road.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the developer tools in Internet Explorer, inspecting the paragraph that was having this problem showed a `-ms-hyphens:auto;` style in your code. You should probably add a style with `-ms-hyphens:auto;` to your block of styles to prevent this from happening.

The style that causes this is placed in http://www.hgsainc.com/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/style.css, at the `* 5.3 Entry Content` part. You can also remove the `hyphens` styles from there to prevent having to do this.